# Вывод записей по двум критериям (логика)

Tags: логика

День добрый!

Уже неделю мучаюсь с формированием вывода по двум критериям. Суть в том что мне нужно сделать вывод записей по месяцам но с лимитом загрузки по 5 штук за раз. Всё это должно работать на ajax по прокрутке страницы.

Делаю так:

1. Получаю из базы массив с датами и
       количеством записей.
2. Выполняю запрос в базу по времени из
       массива с лимитом в 5 записей и
       формирую массив json.
3. На клиентской стороне в ajax
       response перебираю массив и
       append'ом добавляю в нужный блок.

Отдельно вывод либо по месяцам либо по лимиту сделать могу. А так что бы после последней записи в месяце переходил на следующий не могу :(

Подскажите логический порядок действий?

Загрузил скрин из базы для понимания 
http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1401/e2/3235f8c8fc29.jpg

Comment: Очень сложно угадать, что там именно происходит. Но, насколько я понимаю, при некоторых запросах эти 5 записей принадлежат двум разным месяцам (то есть, один за 31 число, второй - за 1 следующего месяца). И здесь проблема с тем, как это все добавить?

Comment: Да, бывают месяца когда запись 1, или её нет вообще

Comment: Нужно четко отслеживать кончились ли записи за месяц или нет, потому как потом нужно делать фильтр по месяцам.

Comment: Вариантов много. Самое простое, пусть в json возвращается на 5 записей, а "максимум 5", но что бы все были за один месяц. Тогда, насколько я понимаю, Ваша логика не пострадает.

Вариант два. При добавлении записи, сравниваем ее месяц с опорным. Если он отличается, то делаем "разбивку" - закрываем старый, открываем новый и опорным месяцем стает месяц с новой записи.

Опорный месяц - это месяц самой последней добавленной записи. Если записи нет, то опорный месяц- "-1".

Comment: По первому варианту, именно так и делаю. В json возвращаю оставшиеся записи, проблема выставить метку, о том, что записи за текущий месяц кончились и нужно при следующем обращении ajax'а уже выбрать следующую запись в массиве дат и работать уже с ней.

Comment: на очень схематическом javascript

   var m = new Date(last_record).getMonth();
   for (var item in json) {
     var cm = item.date.getMonth();
     if (m == -1) { put_start_of_month(cm); m = cm;}
     if (cm != m) {
       put_end_of_month(m);
       put_start_of_month(cm);
       m = cm;}
     put_current_record(item);
    }